# Python - change switch value of array at index between 1 and 0

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I got an numpy array like [[1,0,0,1]].
I wrote the following method to switch the value at a specific index in the array between 1 and 0:

```
'''
@param array: The array from which an value should be inverted
@param index: index at which the value should be inverted
'''
def change_binary_value(array, index):

    if array[index]==0:

        array[index] = 0
    else:
        array[index] = 1
```

So, i am not a every-day user of python and i get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Well, i dont want to use any() or all(). I just want to change a single value. Why does'nt python want me to do that? Thats a bit strange.

Hoping for quick answer,

Fabian

Comment: this code does not generate that error ...

Comment: Also, what do you expect assigning 0 to the variable do when it's already 0?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I do get exactly that error.

Comment: thanks @StefanPochmann ... i was a little to fast ... and didnt notice the sub array :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy has array within array in this case, that is why [0] after array to extract first array is necessary.

Here is the code that will invert the value at specific index (if statement was wrong):

```
def change_binary_value(array, index):

    if array[0][index]==0:
        array[0][index] = 1
    else:
        array[0][index] = 0
    return array
```